# camel-sql под apache-servicemix-5.4.0

Tags: java, java-ee

Проблема старта ]camel-sql (2.14.1) на платформе apache-servicemix-5.4.0. Bundle camel-sql (2.14.1) загружен (отображается по команде list), но не стартует (при вводе команды start). По команде headers с идентификатором camel-sql (2.14.1) выдается информация, что не загружены пакеты

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core;version="[3.2,4)",
org.springframework.jdbc.core.support;version="[3.2,4)"
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource;version="[3.2,4)",
org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob;version="[3.2,4)".
```

Но среди загруженных есть пакет  `mvn:org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.2.11.RELEASE` (загружаемый из Maven-репозитрария). Подскажите, что делать? Искать пакет конкретной версии 3.2.4? Но его нигде нет

Answer (score 1):

По всему не загружен бандл spring-jdbc (он может быть загружен, но неактивен). Возможно ему не хватает каких-то зависимостей (а их там немало).

Очень рекомендую поставить web консоль сервера и через нее все посмотреть. Будет сразу все ясно и понятно. Версию 3.2.4 искать не нужно, о чем говорит скобочка в конце [3.2,4)